# Why does the DBDH simulator have half the advantage of an adversary?

Tags: provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack, abe, proof-of-work

Literature that includes the DBDH assumption such as this [paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/322/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-3-642-19379-8_4.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fchapter%2F10.1007%2F978-3-642-19379-8_4&token2=exp=1495738829~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F322%2Fchp%25253A10.1007%25252F978-3-642-19379-8_4.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fchapter%252F10.1007%252F978-3-642-19379-8_4*~hmac=3b7de0ac6f0b3b098a904641b1262bf2f418770f01d5e1b2a1199a392b1ff04a) or this [paper](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1320000/1315302/p456-cheung.pdf?ip=35.12.208.229&id=1315302&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=B5D9E165A72B697C%2E47E2B4B107F7155E%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=744906944&CFTOKEN=39012483&__acm__=1495738153_c603f82dece6265736ccf4cf0f20d958) has a formal security proof that states:

> Suppose an adversary with non-negligible advantage $\varepsilon = Adv$. A simulator is constructed that can distinguish a DBDH element from a random element with advantage $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Why is the advantage of the simulator ($\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$) half of that the adversary ($\varepsilon$)?

Comment: The link to your second paper is broken. [Did you mean this one?](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/183.pdf) In the first link, I didn't see the bound explicitly listed, but I did in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312299076_A_Ciphertext-Policy_Attribute-Based_Encryption_Based_on_an_Ordered_Binary_Decision_Diagram) which has a similar title. Is this right?